# How to convert dictionary to specific object type

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working on project where I am getting a array of dictionary from server as below

```
[{
    accountAuthorizationType = None;
    accountCategory = Wallet;
    accountClass = wallet;
    accountIdentifier = 0;
    accountRoleExternal = "<null>";
    accountStatusExternal = "<null>";
    accountTypeId = 1;
    attachedToUserDate = "<null>";
    balance = 204;
    ....
    .....
}]
```

In my project I have a SDK file as below

```
    @interface MNFAccount : MNFObject

    ///******************************
    /// @name Immutable properties
    ///******************************

    /**
     @abstract The bank identifier of an account.

     @discussion This value is an identifier for the account set by the originating bank. This identifier is used when getting account statements.
     */
    @property (nonatomic,copy,readonly) NSString *accountIdentifier;

    /**
     @abstract The realm identifier of an account.
     */
    @property (nonatomic,copy,readonly) NSString *realmIdentifier;

    /**
     @abstract The account type identifier of an account.

     @discussion This value is an identifier for the type (savings, checking, etc.) of an account.
     */
    @property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) NSNumber *accountTypeId;

    /**
     @abstract The balance of an account.
     */
    @property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) NSNumber *balance;

......
.....
.......
}
```

properties in class & keys in dict are same.

Now I want to convert dict into MNFAccount object as below

```
      for dict in arrayOfDictOfCard {
            let mnfAccount = dict as? MNFAccount
            print(("mnfAccount is :\(mnfAccount?.accountTypeId)"))
        }
```

but unable to convert.

Please suggest how can I convert response dictionary into MNFAccount object.

Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Comment: get dictionary from json and  set pro[erties  in MNFAccount object array

Comment: properties are read only..Please see in question again.

Comment: then there should be some constructor inside that class or some factory method to populate object.

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/meniga/mobile-sdk-ios/wiki/MNFObject#fetch-an-account

Comment: If a property is read-only the `copy` attribute is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can get Dictionary from array and use

```
var mnfAccount : MNFAccount;
mnfAccount.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(keyedValues: dict);
```